# I hope that can I get family reunion visa for Germany after I'm banned from Slovenia for six months because of expired passport while going to Austria

Tags: visas, family

I am a Nigerian. I live in Croatia and my wife, a Croatia citizen, lives and works in Germany. Recently I was caught with my expired passport by Slovenia police while going to Austria to renew my passport and they issued me six months ban from Slovenia and now I want to apply for a German family reunion visa to join my wife in Germany. Will the ban affect my family reunion visa?

Comment: Can someone explain why this is a duplicate? The duplicate appears to be about a German ban while this one is about a Slovenian ban. Is it because the Slovenian ban will be easily discoverable due to both countries being in the EU and Schengen?

Comment: @mkennedy, both countries would apply the Schengen visa code. There are some slight differences in interpretation between countries, but the basic rules are the same.

Comment: I agree with @mkennedy. Being caught with an expired passport is very different from being caught with **fake documents**.